# CircleCI save output for dependent jobs in workflow

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I have two jobs, B dependant on A and I need to use it's output as input for my next job.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  A:
    docker:
      - image: xxx
    environment:
      MAKEFLAGS: "-i"
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - run: git submodule update --init
      - run:
          name: build A
          command: cd platform/android/ && ant
  B:
    docker:
      - image: yyy
    environment:
      MAKEFLAGS: "-i"
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
          name: build B
          command: ./gradlew assembleDebug

workflows:
  version: 2
  tests:
    jobs:
      - A
      - B:
          requires:
           - A
```

The output of job A in folder `./build/output` needs to be saved and used in job B.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried mounting a volume from host? This way your data will be accessible from A and B, won't be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

You would use CircleCI [Workspaces](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs).

```
version: 2
jobs:
  A:
    docker:
      - image: xxx
    environment:
      MAKEFLAGS: "-i"
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - run: git submodule update --init
      - run:
          name: build A
          command: cd platform/android/ && ant
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: build/
          paths:
            - output
  B:
    docker:
      - image: yyy
    environment:
      MAKEFLAGS: "-i"
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: build/
          name: build B
          command: ./gradlew assembleDebug

workflows:
  version: 2
  tests:
    jobs:
      - A
      - B:
          requires:
           - A
```

Also keep in mind, your B job has some YAML issues.

Comment: Is the indentation of name: build B correct? I have trying to use it but I cannot get it working.

Comment: Use the `circleci config validate` command from the CircleCI CLI to diagnose your config.